# Display image inside a div tag behind that div tag

Tags: html, css

How can I change this:

[image]

just using css, to this (the image is inside that div):

[image]

```
<style>
div {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(150, 150, 150);
    padding-top:150px;
    padding-bottom:150px;
    position: relative;
}

div>img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
}
</style>

<div>
    <img class="first-square" src="img1.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: You are reference to this article [z-index tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
   <div id="square"></div>
   <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100.png" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#square {
   width: 70%;
   margin: 100px auto;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #000;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(150, 150, 150);
   padding-top: 150px;
   padding-bottom: 150px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

#root > img {
   width: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 15%;
   left: 10%;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` and `transform: translate(<value for X coordinate>, <value for Y coordinate>)` will get the job done.

Try with this once, if in doubt still, I will show you how it works.

Happy coding :)

Edit 1:

```css
.small-div{
  height: 50px; 
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -100; 
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 0; 
  left : 0; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  border: 2px solid red
}
.larger-div{
  position: relative; 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="larger-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    // put img here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the translate will only move the image up, down, left and right.. am I right? ..I don't understand how I can apply this styles to get what I want..

Comment: I can help you with this, just clear me a bit with the issue, so you want the image to be displayed behind a div (in the smaller one) right ?

Comment: yes, that is right.. the example is attached in my question.. I have an image inside my div and I want that image to display behind that div

Comment: I have edited my answer, use that code, it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Use the CSS `z-index` property. An element with a lower `z-index` than another will go behind it (note that the position needs to be something other than `static`):

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: It works with `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, or `sticky`